# How to train a DeepLab model with a dataset that contains different size of images without unifying their sizes?

Tags: pytorch, deeplab

I have a dataset that contains different size of images, and I want to train it on a DeepLab model with pytorch without unifying their sizes .
However, I learned that when training with batch , there must be same size in the same batch , unless set batchsize as 1, I'm wondering if there any method to train it, in a custom batch, and not uniform picture size .

Comment: It requires to to have the same size during training because for generating mask there is pre-defined size for segmentation. The only way you should it do scale resizing then pad the rest of the image. Which is called letterbox reszing. I hope it helps.